# Understanding WCF from a layman's point of view

Tags: wcf

I am relatively new to WCF. I am developing Web application.

I am trying to understanding **"Why WCF"** and read many articles .

But in many places it has been mentioned "to developed service oriented architecture ,to asynchronously send data" without any detailed explanation / any basic example.

Can somebody please let me know one simple example in layman's term ,**"Why WCF"** so that I can appreciate its existence.

I have had conversations with many people but none of them were able to answer this basic question.

I am also aware that ,many hundreds of applications have gone live before WCF was there...

Comment: WCF is trying to **consolidate** a lot of previously diverging technologies - like ASMX for web services, possibly with WSE thrown in; MSMQ for queueing; other techniques for using TCP/IP, named pipes etc. - WCF combines those into a **common** framework that can do it all - with **one style** of development (and a lot of configuration options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, you do have a task to make a procedure of recieving of the coordinate point (lat,lon) and and returning the picture of the surrounding area. Or to make a language translator from voise input to text output. These jobs could uses several servers with a lot of data and could makes some huge mathimatic calculations. But you procedure should me quick, **platform independend, secured, protocol-independent, consumed by different technologies** (Web, Mobile, Applications). And at the same time it should be **easy to consume** by the end users, which do know nothing about you. As the main aim of ASP to handle web requests and generate the html responses, so the aim of WCF is to supply the end user with some useful functionality, developed by another user, remotly.

The developer creates a service (WCF) where he specifies its adress, binding and contract. Knowing these parameters other developers can consume this service. They can consume it by ASP, SilverLight, WPF, WinForms or any other technology (even none-microsoft), using SOAP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia:

> The Windows Communication Foundation (or WCF) is an application
>   programming interface (API) in the .NET Framework for building
>   connected, service-oriented applications.
>
> WCF is meant for designing and deploying distributed applications
>   under service-oriented architecture (SOA) implementation. **
>   Architechture
>
> ** WCF is designed using service oriented architecture principles to support distributed computing where services have remote consumers.
>   Clients can consume multiple services; services can be consumed by
>   multiple clients. Services are loosely coupled to each other. Services
>   typically have a WSDL interface (Web Services Description Language)
>   that any WCF client can use to consume the service, regardless of
>   which platform the service is hosted on. WCF implements many advanced
>   Web services (WS) standards such as WS-Addressing,
>   WS-ReliableMessaging and WS-Security. With the release of .NET
>   Framework 4.0, WCF also provides RSS Syndication Services,
>   WS-Discovery, routing and better support for REST services. Endpoint A
>   WCF client connects to a WCF service via an Endpoint. Each service
>   exposes its contract via one or more endpoints. An endpoint has an
>   address (which is a URL specifying where the endpoint can be accessed)
>   and binding properties that specify how the data will be transferred.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation

Useful resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/dd943056%28en-us%29.aspx

http://www.wcftutorial.net/

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_the_WCF_Hello_World_App.aspx

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Writing_your_first_WCF_client.aspx